# mysql can i create an updated_at column for a specific field

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

MYSQL Create a updated_at column for a specific field.

Can i create an updated_at(timestamp) column for a specific column
When i change the specific column, the updated_at column must be changed

Comment: That's already the default behavior....

Comment: You must try creating a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Create a trigger that will watch any update on table

Then check your column change in if clause

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_date BEFORE UPDATE ON myTable 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
IF NEW.column1 <=> OLD.column1 THEN
    SET new.updated_at = NOW()
END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create Mysql triggers to get this done. If you intend to do this from migration, here is a sample code, like which you have to use your table:

```
public function up()
    {
        DB::unprepared('
        CREATE TRIGGER tr_User_Name_Update AFTER UPDATE ON `users` FOR EACH ROW
            BEGIN
               IF NEW.column1 <=> OLD.column1 THEN
                -- RUN YOUR LOGIC HERE--
               END IF;
            END
        ');
    }

    public function down()
    {
        DB::unprepared('DROP TRIGGER `tr_User_Name_Update`');
    }
```

I hope this will help you to kick start.

Answer (score 0):

In your model, you could override the updateTimestamps() method (in the Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasTimestamps trait).

This is how I would do it:

Have an extra `datetime` field in your database table. Say you want to track the `name` column, I would have a `datetime` field called `name_updated_at`.

In your model use this method:

```php
protected function updateTimestamps()
{
    // update the timestamp fields as usual
    parent::updateTimestamps();

    // if the name column has changed, then update the
    // name_updated_at field too
    if ($this->isDirty('name') {
        $this->name_updated_at = $this->freshTimestamp();
    }
    return $this;
}
```

The function is called in the Model's `save()` method (OK, called there through `performInsert()` and `performUpdate()`.

This avoids having application code in MySQL and keeps it in your app.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add more than one column

```
DELIMITER $
CREATE TRIGGER NAME_YOUR_TRIGGER
BEFORE UPDATE ON YOUR_TABLE
BEGIN
IF
 (NEW.COLUMN1 != OLD.COLUMN1) or (NEW.COLUMN2 != OLD.COLUMN2)
          THEN SET NEW.UPDATED_AT = NOW();

END IF;
END
$
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).